# Python 3.12: Using asynchronous infinitely and concurrently to achieve I/O operations

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to print text onto the console, while also listening for input, and if the user presses "enter," that printing would stop. With that "enter", it would then prompt the user to enter a specified value, to which the printing would start again.

The asynchronous functions must be run indefinitely and concurrently.

```
import asyncio
global mode

async def printer():
  while mode:
    print("whatever")

async def inputer():
  while True:
    loop = asyncio
    loop.run_in_executor(None, input) 
    #once the users hits enter, mode will be set to false and printer will stop printing.
    mode = False
    message = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, "Please type your message below + "\n")
    mode = True
    #lets printer print again
```

```
async def main()
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  asyncio.ensure_future(printer())
  asyncio.ensure_future(speaker())
  loop.run_forever()
```

I was expecting the function asyncio.ensure_future to run printer() and speaker() concurrently. This causes for "whatever" to be printed forever, but does not actually allow for the user to press "enter" to stop the printing.

Flipping the functions around results in:

```
async def main()
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  asyncio.ensure_future(speaker())
  asyncio.ensure_future(printer())
  loop.run_forever()
```

This simply causes "assert self._self_reading_future is None". I'm not entirely sure what this means.